# How to remove lines that are doubled only after line containing some string - linux/bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, line

as mentioned in title. I found a command that works so lines that are doubled are removed:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' ~/.bashrc
```

but how to achieve that only after line that contains specific string, sth like:

```
if line is after line with string "hello"
    perl -i.bak -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' ~/.bashrc
```

I am trying to use bash for it.

Comment: 1. Filter all lines before the line containing some string. Output it. 2. Filter all lines after the line containing some string. Pipe it your perl script. Output it. ...

Comment: any clues how to do it?

Comment: Do you *only* want a perl-based answer? I'd be happy to answer for awk, or for native bash with no external tools, but since this is tagged perl...

Comment: I would be VERY happy to use anything else as well :)

Comment: we can help better if you edit your Q to include a small set of sample data and the required output from that same data. You get extra points i you include your best attempt at coding a solution, and show your current output and any error messages. Please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format properly like `code/data/output/ErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: I will remember about this in the future. Someone gave a simple answer that worked perfectly so I won't escalate the issue further. I gave this answer an "arrow up". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the range extraction operator `..`:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if //../hello/ or !$x{$_}++' ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ed, this is very easy.  I also put a '+' sign in all my filenames to serve as a record seperator between the filename and the extension, so I can split them up easily with Cut, but you can remove them if you like.

File+.txt:-

```
hi
hello
hello
there
```

Script+.sh:-

```
#!/bin/sh -x

init () {
cat > edcommands+.txt << EOF
/hello/d
wq
EOF

next
}

end () {
rm ./edcommands+.txt
exit 0
}

next () {
[[ -z $(echo $edresult | grep '?') ]] && main
end
}

main () {
edresult=$(ed -s file+.txt < edcommands+.txt)
next 
}

init
```

Comment: My pleasure. :)